# How to remove space in a value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to clean up this dataframe but I realized that my code didn't include other variations of the **":"** I was trying to remove. In my first column, I'd like to remove the space and the **":"** next to it. How can I include this code to clean it up? When I try to edit the **for col in df.columns[1:]:** function, I keep getting errors or it's not recognizing the column values.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# importing datasets
df=pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df.columns = ['Username','Q1']
df.drop('Username', inplace=True, axis=1)

df[['Q1_Comfortable','Q1_Neither','Q1_Uncomfortable','Q1_Ans']] = df['Q1'].str.split(';',expand=True)


df.drop(columns=['Q1'],inplace=True)
for col in df.columns[1:]:
    df[col] = df[col].str.split(':').str[-1]

df.head()
```

**Original dataframe for Q1**

[image: original]

**Updated dataframe for 1Q**

[image: updated]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `str` method `replace`:

```
df['Q_Confortable'] = df1['Q_Confortable'].str.replace(' : ','')
df.head()
```